# Помощь по vk.sdk.VKAccessToken

Tags: java, android

При нажатии на кнопку вызываю код поделиться новостью:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Bitmap b = getPhoto();
        VKPhotoArray photos = new VKPhotoArray();
        photos.add(new VKApiPhoto("photo-47200925_314622346"));
        new VKShareDialog()
                .setText("I created this post with VK Android SDK\nSee additional information below\n#vksdk")
                .setUploadedPhotos(photos)
                .setAttachmentImages(new VKUploadImage[]{
                        new VKUploadImage(b, VKImageParameters.pngImage())
                })
                .setAttachmentLink("VK Android SDK information", "https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk")
                .setShareDialogListener(new VKShareDialog.VKShareDialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVkShareComplete(int postId) {
                        b.recycle();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVkShareCancel() {
                        b.recycle();
                    }
                })
                .show(getFragmentManager(), "VK_SHARE_DIALOG");
    }
});
```

Все хорошо показывается и открывается, но когда нажимаю отправить на стену, то вылетает ошибка:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken.userId' on a null object reference
    at com.vk.sdk.dialogs.VKShareDialog.makePostWithAttachments(VKShareDialog.java:383)
    at com.vk.sdk.dialogs.VKShareDialog.access$600(VKShareDialog.java:104)
    at com.vk.sdk.dialogs.VKShareDialog$5.onClick(VKShareDialog.java:424)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Токен вроде получил. Из-за чего могла возникнуть ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день.
Мне кажется, что при авторизации вы не сохранили токен в SharedPreferences.

Попробуйте покопать в эту сторону(при авторизации):

```
 VKAccessToken.saveTokenToSharedPreferences(android.content.Context ctx,java.lang.String tokenKey)
```

Comment: делал так вроде:

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    VKUIHelper.onCreate(getActivity());
                    VKSdk.initialize(listener, APP_ID, VKAccessToken.tokenFromSharedPreferences(getActivity(), VK_SDK_ACCESS_TOKEN_PREF_KEY));
                    VKSdk.authorize(sMyScope, true, false);

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в onCreate следующую проверку:         if (!(VKSdk.wakeUpSession())) {
            VKSdk.authorize("friends, photos, wall");
        }

Comment: неа....сразу же ошибку бьет, мол типа токен не сохранен был.....
А может все дело в запросе(все указал, а User ID нет)?

Comment: Нет, не в этом дело. Если user не указан, то возвращает текущего.

Comment: кароче if (VKSdk.wakeUpSession()) { VKSdk.authorize("wall"); } прикрутил! Все работает, но прежняя ошибка осталась!!!! В дебаге возвращает  userId == null;